# Saving an image state in uitableviewcell using nsuserdefault

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've been toiling over this problem for a few weeks, I'm embarrassed to say, and have searched all over stack overflow and the internet but cannot find anything that works for me. I've come across some very vague answers that say, "Well, use these two lines of code, then add these two lines, then maybe throw it into a property..." What the heck?  No one ever says where to put the code and very few address what needs to be done in the cellForRowAtIndexpath.  I have tried many things!

I simply want to save the state of a UIImage in my tableview cells.  Basically, the user can tap the image in the tableview cell and when they do so, a UIAlertview pops up.  They can choose whether or not they have used the type of transportation listed in the tableview.  If 'yes', the image color changes to blue (instead of gray) indicating that they have used it.  Alternately, they can de-select the image by tapping 'no' and the image goes back to its gray state.  I want to be able to persist this action using nsuserdefaults since there is only a small amount of information to be saved (essentially just the image state).  Nothing I've tried will save the information. I will add my code below and wish pounds of happiness to whomever can help me with this!

Alternatively, I have created the transportation objects from a custom class.  Is there a way to set a bool in the custom class, change it dynamically when the user chooses yes or no, and then update the custom class so it saves the information?  Any ideas would be appreciated!

**Main ViewController**

```
@interface MainTableViewController ()
{
    NSMutableArray *selectedImages;
}


@end

@implementation MainTableViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _transportController = [[TransportDataController alloc] init];
    self.dataSource = _transportController.populateDataSource;
    self.title = @"Transportation Types";

   selectedImages = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"selected"] mutableCopy];


}


-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return _dataSource.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"mainCell";
    TransportCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[TransportCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    Transport *transportData = [self.dataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.nameLabel.text = transportData.name;
    cell.transportImageView.image = transportData.transportImage;


    if (transportData.usedTransportIsSelected == NO)
    {
        cell.grayedImageView.image = transportData.usedTransportImage;


    }
    else if (transportData.usedTransportIsSelected == YES)
    {
        cell.grayedImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"stamp-color"];


    }


    UITapGestureRecognizer *grayedImageTouched = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(transportImageTapped:)];
    grayedImageTouched.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    cell.grayedImageView.tag = indexPath.row;
    [cell.grayedImageView addGestureRecognizer:grayedImageTouched];
    cell.grayedImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;



    return cell;
}


-(void)transportImageTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    Transport *transportData = [self.dataSource objectAtIndex:gesture.view.tag];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:gesture.view.tag inSection:0];


    UIAlertController *transportAlert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Yes, it's true..." message:@"I have used this type of transport before." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    [transportAlert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){

        NSLog(@"cancel");

    }]];

    [transportAlert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Yes" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){

        UIImage *darkImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"stamp-color"];
        transportData.usedTransportImage = darkImage;
        transportData.usedTransportIsSelected = YES;
        [self.dataSource replaceObjectAtIndex:gesture.view.tag withObject:transportData];
        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"selected"];
        [defaults synchronize];

        NSLog(@"has taken this transport before");

    }]];

    [transportAlert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"No" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){

        UIImage *grayedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"stamp-grayed"];
        transportData.usedTransportImage = grayedImage;
        transportData.usedTransportIsSelected = NO;
        [self.dataSource replaceObjectAtIndex:gesture.view.tag withObject:transportData];
        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults setBool:NO forKey:@"selected"];
        [defaults synchronize];

        NSLog(@"has not taken this transport before");

    }]];

    [self presentViewController:transportAlert animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might make more sense for you to modify your `Transport` class; assuming it has attached to it some unique identifier.

```
@interface Transport
@property (strong) id somethingThatUniquelyIdentifiesThisTransport;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL usedTransportIsSelected;
// ...
@end

@implementation Transport
- (void)setUsedTransportIsSelected:(BOOL)value {
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@(value) forKey:self.somethingThatUniquelyIdentifiesThisTransport];
}

- (BOOL)usedTransportIsSelected {
  return [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:self.somethingThatUniquelyIdentifiesThisTransport] boolValue];
}

// ...
@end
```

Comment: This looks intriguing but I'm not sure I understand how to set up a unique identifier for each type of transport.  They all have a different name.  Would that work? Something like, property (strong) id transportName; ?

Comment: Sure. Anything that's unique about your objects that will allow you to identify them in `NSUserDefaults`. Using an existing property that you know to be unique is your best option; otherwise you have to append supporting data to your original dataset.

Comment: You could use the `transportData.name` property that you have already if you know that it's unique. You don't have to create a duplicate property named `transportName`.

Comment: Wow! That seems to have done it.  It looks like everything is currently saving.  --I'm doing a happy dance--  Thanks very much!

Comment: You may want to consider writing this data out with your original dataset instead of to its own `NSUserDefaults` keys. Obviously that doesn't make sense if your dataset is read-only and modifying data architecture is outside of the scope of this question.

Comment: Ok, you lost me there.  I removed all the NSUserDefault code from my MainViewController and am using the suggested code above in my Transport Class.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: My comment was referring to the idea that you're already storing "Transport data" somewhere in an object that you've called `dataSource`. You should consider storing this data with the rest of the Transport data instead of a one-off `NSUserDefaults` set of keys.

Comment: Oh! I thought that's what we are doing here.  The key I used is self.name, so I assumed that the save became tied into my datasource by doing that. Am I assuming wrong? lol.  Everything I learn is opening my understanding of objC but I'm still quite the noob! I will update my code below and include my datasource.

Comment: Oh you hard-code the data in the app. I had just assumed you were loading it from a database / file / URL. `NSUserDefaults` is fine for you, then.

Comment: Wonderful.  This is my practice app.  My final app will have a defined amount of data like this one does. I'm happy to know that your solution is sufficient.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code in case it should be helpful to anyone.

**MainViewController**

```
#import "MainTableViewController.h"
#import "TransportCell.h"

@interface MainTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation MainTableViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _transportController = [[TransportDataController alloc] init];
    self.dataSource = _transportController.populateDataSource;
    self.title = @"Transportation Types";

}


-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return _dataSource.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"mainCell";
    TransportCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[TransportCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    Transport *transportData = [self.dataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.nameLabel.text = transportData.name;
    cell.transportImageView.image = transportData.transportImage;


    if (transportData.usedTransportIsSelected == NO)
    {
        cell.grayedImageView.image = transportData.usedTransportImage;
    }
    else if (transportData.usedTransportIsSelected == YES)
    {
        cell.grayedImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"stamp-color"];
    }


    UITapGestureRecognizer *grayedImageTouched = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(transportImageTapped:)];
    grayedImageTouched.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    cell.grayedImageView.tag = indexPath.row;
    [cell.grayedImageView addGestureRecognizer:grayedImageTouched];
    cell.grayedImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;


    return cell;
}


-(void)transportImageTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    Transport *transportData = [self.dataSource objectAtIndex:gesture.view.tag];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:gesture.view.tag inSection:0];


    UIAlertController *transportAlert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Yes, it's true..." message:@"I have used this type of transport before." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    [transportAlert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){

        NSLog(@"cancel");

    }]];

    [transportAlert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Yes" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){

        UIImage *darkImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"stamp-color"];
        transportData.usedTransportImage = darkImage;
        transportData.usedTransportIsSelected = YES;
        [self.dataSource replaceObjectAtIndex:gesture.view.tag withObject:transportData];
        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

        NSLog(@"has taken this transport before");

    }]];

    [transportAlert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"No" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){

        UIImage *grayedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"stamp-grayed"];
        transportData.usedTransportImage = grayedImage;
        transportData.usedTransportIsSelected = NO;
        [self.dataSource replaceObjectAtIndex:gesture.view.tag withObject:transportData];
        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];


        NSLog(@"has not taken this transport before");

    }]];

    [self presentViewController:transportAlert animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

**Transport.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Transport : NSObject 

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *transportImage;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *usedTransportImage;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL usedTransportIsSelected;

@end
```

**Transport.m**

```
#import "Transport.h"

@implementation Transport

-(void)setUsedTransportIsSelected:(BOOL)value
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@(value) forKey:self.name];
}

-(BOOL)usedTransportIsSelected
{
    return [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:self.name] boolValue];
}

@end
```

**TransportDataController.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Transport.h"

@interface TransportDataController : NSObject 

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *transportDataArray;

-(NSMutableArray *)populateDataSource;

@end
```

**TransportDataController.m**

```
#import "TransportDataController.h"

@implementation TransportDataController

-(NSMutableArray *)populateDataSource
{
    _transportDataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    Transport *transportData = [[Transport alloc] init];

    transportData.name = @"Bus";
    transportData.transportImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Bus"];
    transportData.usedTransportImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"stamp-grayed"];
    [_transportDataArray addObject:transportData];

    transportData = [[Transport alloc] init];
    transportData.name = @"Helicopter";
    transportData.transportImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Helicopter"];
    transportData.usedTransportImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"stamp-grayed"];
    [_transportDataArray addObject:transportData];

    transportData = [[Transport alloc] init];
    transportData.name = @"Truck";
    transportData.transportImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Truck"];
    transportData.usedTransportImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"stamp-grayed"];
    [_transportDataArray addObject:transportData];

    transportData = [[Transport alloc] init];
    transportData.name = @"Boat";
    transportData.transportImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Boat"];
    transportData.usedTransportImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"stamp-grayed"];
    [_transportDataArray addObject:transportData];

    transportData = [[Transport alloc] init];
    transportData.name = @"Bicycle";
    transportData.transportImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Bicycle"];
    transportData.usedTransportImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"stamp-grayed"];
    [_transportDataArray addObject:transportData];

    transportData = [[Transport alloc] init];
    transportData.name = @"Motorcycle";
    transportData.transportImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Motorcycle"];
    transportData.usedTransportImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"stamp-grayed"];
    [_transportDataArray addObject:transportData];

    transportData = [[Transport alloc] init];
    transportData.name = @"Plane";
    transportData.transportImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Plane"];
    transportData.usedTransportImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"stamp-grayed"];
    [_transportDataArray addObject:transportData];

    transportData = [[Transport alloc] init];
    transportData.name = @"Train";
    transportData.transportImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Train"];
    transportData.usedTransportImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"stamp-grayed"];
    [_transportDataArray addObject:transportData];

    transportData = [[Transport alloc] init];
    transportData.name = @"Car";
    transportData.transportImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Car"];
    transportData.usedTransportImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"stamp-grayed"];
    [_transportDataArray addObject:transportData];

    transportData = [[Transport alloc] init];
    transportData.name = @"Scooter";
    transportData.transportImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Scooter"];
    transportData.usedTransportImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"stamp-grayed"];
    [_transportDataArray addObject:transportData];

    transportData = [[Transport alloc] init];
    transportData.name = @"Caravan";
    transportData.transportImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Caravan"];
    transportData.usedTransportImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"stamp-grayed"];
    [_transportDataArray addObject:transportData];

    return _transportDataArray;


}
```